# I have added a database in my program. Although the build is successful my app is crashing. This is my databasehandler;

Tags: sqlite

I am getting the error as:

```
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                    (near "EXISTSnotes": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTSnotes(idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY,titleTEXT,descriptionTEXT)).
```

Need help.

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DatabaseValues.DATABASE_NAME, null, DatabaseValues.DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { db.execSQL(DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES_CREATE); }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES_DROP);
    onCreate(db);
}
public void addNote(Note note) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues noteValues = new ContentValues();
    noteValues.put(DatabaseValues.NOTES_TITLE, note.getTitle());
    noteValues.put(DatabaseValues.NOTES_DESCRIPTION, note.getDescription());

    db.insert(DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES, null, noteValues);
    db.close();
}

public void updateNote(Note note) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues noteValues = new ContentValues();
    noteValues.put(DatabaseValues.NOTES_TITLE, note.getTitle());
    noteValues.put(DatabaseValues.NOTES_DESCRIPTION, note.getDescription());

    db.update(DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES, noteValues, DatabaseValues.NOTES_ID + "= ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(note.getId())});
    db.close();
}

public void deleteNote(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM" + DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES + "WHERE" + DatabaseValues.NOTES_ID + "= '" + "id" + "'";

    db.execSQL(deleteQuery);
    db.close();
}

public List<Note> getAllNotes() {
    List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM" + DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            Note note = new Note();
            note.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            note.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            note.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));

            notes.add(note);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return notes;
}
```

}

Comment: You need some whitespace in there.

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: @ManasiKutwal still doesn't work.. but getting the same error?

Comment: can you show the content of: `DatabaseValues.TABLE_NOTES_CREATE` ?

Comment: public static final String TABLE_NOTES_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TABLE_NOTES + "(" + NOTES_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + NOTES_TITLE + "TEXT," + NOTES_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT)";        @apineda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be clear enough to see what's going on:

**while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTSnotes(idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY,titleTEXT,descriptionTEXT)).**

Your query for creating the Db seems to be missing a whitespace between 'EXISTS' and the table name 'note'.

***UPDATE***

You are actually missing many more whitespace. Format your query like this and make sure all others query you build have the correct whitespacing or they will fail as well.

public static final String TABLE_NOTES_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTES + " (" + NOTES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + NOTES_TITLE + " TEXT," + NOTES_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT)";

Comment: Yes! i was missing on white spaces.My app works now! Thanks